# Play a 2nd flash video after the first ends

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I have a flash object set up in the standard format:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("swfplayer.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9", "expressInstall.swf");
</script>
```

but I want to start playing a second flash video on a different part of the web page the moment the first video ends. Is there a kind of listener of some sort to use?

Thanks

Comment: is there an actual video in the flash movie? Does the flash movie always play for the same length of time?

Comment: yes, theres a flv video and the length is fixed

Answer (score 2):

There actually is a way to do this, providing you movie is more or less timeline based. There's a couple calls that you can make to the flash object through javascript that will return you values you can check against to determine if the movie is complete.

To retrieve the current frame of the movie use:

```
document.getElementById("myFlashObject").TCurrentFrame("_root");
```

To check if the movie is playing use:

```
document.getElementById("myFlashObject").IsPlaying()
```

If the movie is stopped on a frame using the "stop()" method, this will return false. There's quite a few other methods you can use as well that you might find useful in playing the other movie. Here's a link to the Adobe reference docs:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html

**Note:** *I tested this and it works with the flash player 10 in firefox. You may want to double check the cross-browser compatibility of these methods.*

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it from these two possibilities:  **LocalConnection** or **ExternalInterface**.

I would go with **ExternalInterface** personally.  With it, you can set up a javascript function that receives a call from videoPlayer_1 when its video has ended.  To this javascript function you could pass an ID to determine which player has finished, and then send a call back up to the appropriate next player to tell it to start playing.  You could repeat this process as many times as you have/swf's with videos.

I would have included an example but you didn't mention as2 or 3.

As for **LocalConnection**, you could create a group of movies with a local data connection, but this is easily broken by certain scenarios of multiple browsers/swfs, so probably not the most reliable method.  However if you wanted to give it a shot, look up Grant Skinner's SwfBridge class to make  things much easier.

Comment: How can I achieve this in javascript

Comment: only javascript?  You do not have access to the .fla?

Comment: i do, but I'm not proficient in actionscript and was wondering if it could be done in javascript

Comment: well that's where I politely bow out.  I can help with the ActionScript and simple JS involved if you need to try the ExternalInterface route.

Comment: @kingsley I'm with Ribs on this one I think your best route is to modify the AS code to make a call using the static methods on ExternalInterface into javascript then in javascript make another method call on the secondary swf again will need to modify with the appropriate static method from ExternalInterface, if you have the source for both swf files the modifications to get this working won't be much AS code so no need to fret.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Detecting end of Flash movie in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755181/detecting-end-of-flash-movie-in-javascript)